# How can I allow http requests from SSL enabled servers

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

We have installed SSL certificate in one server from there we need to call API calls on another server which is on HTTP.

I am getting error :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'HTTPS URL' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'API URL ON HTTP'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can Anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: can you be more specific about the end points? Is it publicly available? Do they have https access?

Comment: Yes Richard, It is available on public with http access.

Comment: my website is running on https://mywebsite.com/#/dashboard and endpoints will be http://apiserver.com/api/v1/getUserCount. Through ajax. i am trying to call api server

Comment: I've found this about ssl with cdata.com. http://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/apps-secure-server.rst Is it related? Otherwise you need to pursuit their support or documentation to get https access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery load https url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663615/jquery-load-https-url)