# Unable to call GIPHY API

Tags: jquery, ajax, giphy, giphy-api

I have a text box and a search button. Based on user input, I want to query Giphy api to fetch matching Gifs. but my ajax call always going to error.
Can anybody help me,

```
 $('#button2').click(function() {
   var srchParam = $('#srcCriteria').val();

   $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=dog&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
   alert("hello");
    //console.log(response.data[0].bitly_url);
   },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     alert("bye");
   }
 }); 
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Appy169/faedybhf/12/

Comment: Why do you do `var srchParam = $('#srcCriteria').val();` and use `$('#srcCriteria').val();` in the get parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in **url** on *jsfiddle*. If you check the console you will see this message:

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=test&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC”

What this means you ask? It means that you are calling `http` from `https`.

Just for testing you can change the url to `//api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + $('#srcCriteria').val() +  "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC`

and you will see it works.

Updated working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/faedybhf/16/)**.

Comment: check the latest jsfiddle. the images are not loading.. But when opened in new tab they shows up https://jsfiddle.net/Appy169/faedybhf/29/

Comment: @ArpitaDutta, The url you are now using it's not actually the url to an image, but to a tool/page of the giphy site. Use `response.data[0].images.fixed_height.url` https://jsfiddle.net/faedybhf/30/. Inspect the object `response.data[0].images` you can see that there are multiple sizes. Including original which you can get using `response.data[0].images.original.url`

Comment: You are a genious. Thank you AGAIN

Answer (score 3):

Use the "upgrade-insecure-requests" CSP directive in the HTML head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

My issue was the embed_url link (https) redirects to a giffy s3 bucket (http) causing a 'mixed content' error. By setting the "Content-Security-Policy" to "upgrade-insecure-requests", all requests made from your html will be over https (except for 'navigational') 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Http** from your URL.

```
var srchParam = $('#srcCriteria').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "//api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + srchParam  +  "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
    //alert("hello");
        console.log(response.data);
    },
   error: function (e) {
   alert(e);
   }
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/faedybhf/25/)

For more information visit [Mixed Content Error (Http/Https)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30696515/2798643)

Comment: Also had a similar problem, but it may help others to know that these URL's are case sensitive. If the case is not respected then you may get a "This content is not available" gif.